# Remove blank page after appendix in latex

Tags: latex

I have a little problem when adding the appendices to my report, I want to add appendices page then two chapters inside it for two appendix

my code now is this:

```
%--------------------------------------% 

% Add references

\newpage

\renewcommand{\bibname{References}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}\bibliography{MyRef}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}

%--------------------------------------%

\begin{appendices}

\appendixpage

\addappheadtotoc

\section*{Appendix A}

 \label{appendix A}

\subsection*{Form for gathering text data}

\input{project/appendixA.tex}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix A}

\section*{Appendix B} \label{appendix B}

\subsection*{Screen shoot of the model deemo} 

\input{project/appendixB.tex}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix B}

\end{appendices}

%--------------------------------------%
```

problems:

- pages on the content table are wrong
- there is a blank page after the title page "appendices"

Comment: Please make a [mre], a small test document that is compilable and reproduces your problem. Please remember that we don't have access to the files on your computer, so the test document should be self sustained.

Comment: This may be better suited for [TeX Stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com).